# How to do multiple replaces on the same line in vi?

Tags: vi

In vi, I will typically do a "confirm" find and replace just by using this: `:%s/find/replace/c`.

Well, the problem with that is when I have some code like this:

```
#this will find this and won't find the next one.
```

Then it asks me to confirm if I want to replace the first instance of `find`, but it skips over the second one for some reason.

How do I make it prompt me for every occurrence of the word `find` rather than only the first one in each line?

Answer (score 2):

Use the global parameter `g`

`:%s/find/replace/gc`